# setting state with if else using flutter

Tags: flutter, if-statement, setstate

long time listener, first time caller. I am not a developer, but trying to make a useful program for myself and some colleagues. The app is used to display pdf's that I have saved on firebase, but I want the UI to vary based on if the file has been downloaded or not. The pdf would be displayed on a card with options to view online or download, while a second car would have options to view, share, and delete. To do this I am trying to use an if else after a check if the file exists. But I don't really know how to manipulate the set state to change my isDownloaded variable to alter the state. Here is the code snippet that I'm working with, I don't get an error, just the isDownloaded state never changes unless hardcoded. localPath is a variable for the local documents directory.
Thanks for the help with this!

```
class RefCardType extends StatefulWidget {
  const RefCardType(
  {Key? key,
  required this.urlPath,
  required this.fileName,
  required this.page,
  required this.title,
  required this.cardTitle,
  required this.cardSubTitle})
  : super(key: key);
   final String urlPath;
   final String fileName;
   final int page;
   final String title;
   final String cardTitle;
   final String cardSubTitle;

   @override
   _RefCardTypeState createState() => _RefCardTypeState();}

class _RefCardTypeState extends State<RefCardType> {
  void checkFile() async {
  File file = File('$localPath/${widget.fileName}');

  if (await file.exists() == true) {
  setState(() {
    isDownloaded = true;
  });
  {
    setState(() {
      isDownloaded = false;
    });
   }
  }
 }

bool isDownloaded = true;

@override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  if (isDownloaded == true) {
  return refFileCard(context,
      urlPath: widget.urlPath,
      fileName: widget.fileName,
      page: widget.page,
      title: widget.title,
      cardTitle: widget.cardTitle,
      cardSubTitle: widget.cardSubTitle);
   } else {
   return refUrlCard(context,
      urlPath: widget.urlPath,
      fileName: widget.fileName,
      page: widget.page,
      title: widget.title,
      cardTitle: widget.cardTitle,
      cardSubTitle: widget.cardSubTitle);
   }
  }
 }
```

Comment: it seems you trying to change isDownloaded inside the class not inside the function

Comment: Thank you @InUser What I'm trying to do is when the RefCardType class is called it checks to see if the file exists and if it does to show card style A. If it does't exists to show card style B. My thought was the class is called then running top down it would process the check file method which would update the isDownloaded variable accordingly. They the if else logic would act on the variable state. I'm guessing that's not correct?

Comment: I'm not sure what language you use but the guideline is that you should call the methods of the class to perform an action. It's not working row by row  like it's working in the main for example ( main is method not class )

Comment: Sorry, should have said this is using flutter